# Passing props to VueJS component thru v-repeat turns up empty

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a bit new to VueJS. I have this Blade template, which is passed the variable `$plans` which contains `[{id:1,name:'1st Plan'},{id:2,name:'2nd Plan'}]`:

```
@extends('layouts.backend')

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::user()->can('edit-plans'))
        <edit-plans
                :workouts="{!! json_encode($plans) !!}"
        ></edit-plans>
    @endif
@endsection
```

Within `edit.vue`:

```
<template>
    <workout
        v-repeat="workouts"
    ></workout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'workouts'
        ]
    }
</script>
```

Within `workouts.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div>{{ id }} :: {{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [

        ]
    }
</script>
```

I have these templates registered globally:

```
Vue.component('edit-plans', require('./components/plans/edit.vue'));
Vue.component('workout', require('./components/plans/workout.vue'));
```

When I compile with `yarn`, I simply get one line with `::` in it but no`id` or `name` values showing up on two lines as expected.

when I check the Chrome Vue JS developer extension, I see this in the `EditPlans` component...

[image: EditPlans]

...but nothing in the `Workouts` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **edit.vue** declare the `v-for` (instead of `v-repeat`) and pass the `props`. In **workout.vue**, declare the `props` so they are available in the template.

**edit.vue:**

```html
<template>
    <workout
        v-for="workout in workouts" :id="workout.id" :name="workout.name"  :key="workout.id"
    ></workout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['workouts']
    }
</script>
```

**workout.vue:**

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ id }} :: {{ name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['id', 'name']
    }
</script>
```

Demo:

```js
Vue.component('edit-plans', {
    template: "#edit-plans-tpl",
  props: ['workouts']
});
Vue.component('workout', {
  template: "#workout-tpl",
  props: ['id', 'name']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: [1,2]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="edit-plans-tpl">
<div>
    <workout
        v-for="workout in workouts" :id="workout.id" :name="workout.name" :key="workout.id"
    ></workout>
</div>
</template>
<template id="workout-tpl">
    <div>{{ id }} :: {{ name }}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <edit-plans :workouts='[{"id":1,"name":"1st Plan"}, {"id":2,"name":"2nd Plan"}]'>
    
  </edit-plans>
</div>
```

> **Update, per comment:**  What if I just want to pass each full `workout` into the child instead of each part of the object? In other words, I'd be able to do `{{ workout.id }} :: {{ workout.name }}`

You can use `v-bind` for that. Just change the **edit.vue**, keep **workout.vue** the same as above.

**edit.vue:**

```html
<template>
    <workout
        v-for="workout in workouts" v-bind="workout" :key="workout.id"
    ></workout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['workouts']
    }
</script>
```

**workout.vue:** same as above.

Demo for this:

```js
Vue.component('edit-plans', {
    template: "#edit-plans-tpl",
  props: ['workouts']
});
Vue.component('workout', {
  template: "#workout-tpl",
  props: ['id', 'name']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: [1,2]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="edit-plans-tpl">
<div>
    <workout
        v-for="workout in workouts" v-bind="workout" :id="workout.id"
    ></workout>
</div>
</template>
<template id="workout-tpl">
    <div>{{ id }} :: {{ name }}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <edit-plans :workouts='[{"id":1,"name":"1st Plan"}, {"id":2,"name":"2nd Plan"}]'>
    
  </edit-plans>
</div>
```

> **Update, per comment:** So no matter what, I have to declare every property within the `workout` object? I can't just do `props: ['workout']` within the **workout.vue** so I can do `{{ workout.id }} :: {{ workout.name }}`?

You can declare the `workout` prop in the child and pass it in the parent like `:workout="workout"`:

**edit.vue:**

```html
<template>
    <workout
        v-for="workout in workouts" :workout="workout" :key="workout.id"
    ></workout>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['workouts']
    }
</script>
```

**workout.vue:**

```html
<template>
    <div>{{ workout.id }} :: {{ workout.name }}</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['workout']
    }
</script>
```

Demo for this:

```js
Vue.component('edit-plans', {
    template: "#edit-plans-tpl",
  props: ['workouts']
});
Vue.component('workout', {
  template: "#workout-tpl",
  props: ['workout']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: [1,2]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="edit-plans-tpl">
<div>
    <workout
        v-for="workout in workouts" :workout="workout" :key="workout.id"
    ></workout>
</div>
</template>
<template id="workout-tpl">
    <div>{{ workout.id }} :: {{ workout.name }}</div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <edit-plans :workouts='[{"id":1,"name":"1st Plan"}, {"id":2,"name":"2nd Plan"}]'>
    
  </edit-plans>
</div>
```

Note: [`:key="workout.id"` **added** to the loop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component): This default mode is efficient, but only suitable when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM state. (thanks [@channasmcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206064/channasmcs)).

Comment: What if I just want to pass each full `workout` into the child instead of each part of the object? In other words, I'd be able to do `{{ workout.id }} :: {{ workout.name }}`. Originally I thought  I needed to access each part as separate properties, but it would be ideal to have the whole `workout` object passed.

Comment: yes this is correct way v-for if stranded way for loop

Comment: So no matter what, I have to declare every property within the `workout` object? I can't just do `props: ['workout']` within the `workout.vue` so I can do `{{ workout.id }} :: {{ workout.name }}`?